# How to configure a BIND 9 name server as a slave for a zone that exists in multiple views?

Tags: dns, bind

I have a Bind9 hidden primary configured with views, and I need a secondary to transfer all the views of the same zone. Example:

On **primary**:

```
view "dmz-view" {
        match-clients { server-dmz; };
        allow-transfer { transfer-dmz; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-query-cache { server-dmz; };
        zone "example.com" IN {
                type master;
                file "/var/cache/bind/db.dmz.example.com";
                notify yes;
        };
};
view "untrust-view" {
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-transfer { transfer-untrust; };
        recursion no;
        zone "example.com" IN {
                type master;
                file "/var/cache/bind/db.untrust.example.com";
                notify yes;
        };
};
```

Now, my problem is that if I put the secondary's IP in both acls (transfer-dmz and transfer-untrust), it will match the first view and will transfer only that.
I've read examples 3,4 in https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00851 but it doesn't seem to fit my needs (or am I misunderstanding?)

I also read https://flylib.com/books/en/2.684.1/setting_up_a_slave_name_server_for_a_zone_in_multiple_views.html but since it's aged I suppose it's outdated .

Any cookbook or advice?

Comment: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00851 you define a key for each view. The secondary uses the key to tell the primary which view it wants, and the primary also uses the key to NOTIFY the secondary which view has updated. I've not tried this myself. Yet.

Comment: So, does it mean that if I define a key for different views and I tell the secondary to announce with a key to transfer the first view, and the other key to stransfer the second view, it transfers all the views? Doesn't it stop on first match (aka when using the first key)

Comment: I believe so, yes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was like said in comments: after some effort I was able to use keys in acl to correctly address zone transfers with their views.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).